# confusion with c2dm messaging in android

Tags: android, android-c2dm

i have implemented a small demo that uses this c2dm code http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html .it works.i am getting push notifications from server but the problem is whenever i send notification from server it sends old notification.It only sends current new notification whenever i register my android device and send registration id to server.Please suggest me what should be the issue.Thanks in advance..

Comment: the content code is same as the link i have post in my question

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember from when I followed Lars Vogel's tutorial myself, I had the same problem. It's actually not the problem that you have stated.

Try putting a breakpoint in the onReceive() function to manually see the payload you are getting. In my case, the message was good, but the `MessageReceivedActivity` was not, and it was always showing the bad message.

Put the `super.onCreate()` method from the MessageReceivedActivity on top of the method.

**How it is:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String message = extras.getString("payload");
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
            TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
            view.setText(message);
        }
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

**How it should be:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String message = extras.getString("payload");
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
            TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
            view.setText(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @RaulGogo helped a bit, but did not solve the problem for me. To see this solution  here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10079537/264618 and read my comments below.

In general change this code in C2DMMessageReceiver class:

```
int ukey = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, ukey,
            intent, 0);
```

and add this in MessageReceivedActivity class:

```
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);//important!
```

Note: setIntent(intent) call refreshes intent with current data.